# simple scan program when scanning photo the picture is surrounded by a massive amount of whitespace, how to remove white space via cli batch

Tags: command-line, scanner, imagemagick, simplescan

See [this photo](https://goo.gl/photos/xeavHxUac5AtdNMYA) and click on the picture.

It is a scan of a print. Simple Scan scanned the image and a large amount of white space.
On the command line, how do I batch remove the white space from the 39 files `*.png` files.

Is there some way to prevent this in the future?

The following did not work.

```
find ./ -name "*.png" -exec convert {} -trim /home/nate/Pictures/magik-converted/{} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

-trim won't work because of the black lines along the left and top borders and because some of the "white" area isn't exactly white.  If those edges are present in all of your images, crop those off first, then add a white border so all 4 corners are white, then trim, for example:

```
convert "Scanned Document-04.png" -shave 10x10 \
        -bordercolor white -border 1x1  -fuzz 20% -trim trimmed.png
```

- The -shave option removes the black edges
- The -bordercolor white and -border 1x1 add a thin white border
- The -fuzz 20% is needed because some of your "white" pixels are not exactly white.
- The -trim option removes the nearly white borders, including the big area you were originally wanting to remove.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do.

convert 1.png -shave 50x50 -bordercolor white -border 1x1  -fuzz 70% -trim trimmed.png

Otherwise it wouldn't work.  So with above command it works.

Solved.  Mark as solved.